# Should Ember addons also follow Ember 2.x project version numbers?

Tags: ember.js

Referring to the [The Ember project blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/16/ember-project-at-2-0.html)

> Starting with Ember 2.0, we will coordinate every release of Ember with releases of the main ecosystem tools maintained by the core team

Should community add-ons follow the same versioning conventions?

I haven't read any recommandation anywhere from core team, and I started to use the same versioning for add-ons I developed, though I'm wondering if it is a good practice or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that if one's addon is really tied to Ember like `ember-cli` or `ember-animate`, then it is good practice to follow their version numbers (and their release cycles).

If an addon can live on its own or is not tied to specific version of Ember, then following Ember release cycles is more a hindrance than a help.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if it is a good practice or not.

It's definitely good practice, because you make promise to users of your addon, that it will work with specified Ember version and it's easier for them to figure out if there will be any compatibility issues.

Crucial addons for Ember ecosystem follow this practice to make developers' lifes easier. Previously you had to figure out which version of Ember Data would work with Ember and which version of Ember CLI would work with Ember. It was confusing and required more attention from developers.

Comment: What bothers me is that any addon API change, even a major one, will fall onto patch version to keep Ember version mirroring, which means that versioning will not be semantic anymore.
Users will know it works with a specific version of Ember, and may be most of them will be fine with that, but that may lead to very unexpected behaviors from non-major addons.